# Как вывести содержимое файла, имя которого хранится в ACF?

Tags: wordpress, acf

В ACF хранится имя файла, default.php
Нужно вывести его содержимое в темплейте.
Можно пример, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $test = the_field('default'); 

include_once( $test );// попробуй так и вдруг где ошибки '' может пропустил)
?>
```

Comment: К сожалению это не работает. include_once ('dir/').the_field ('default'); ? или include или file_get_contents это все выводит только URL до файла, но не его содержимое. Только если сразу полный путь до файла указывать, тогда работает. То есть не составной путь /dir/ + default.php, а сразу весь путь до файла из поля.

Comment: Какая задача у вас ? acf это же произвольные поля я не знаю как они к файлам php относятся? если вам нужно из acf имя файла взять который будет вставляться как вам нужно то совместите the_field и include через переменные или как хотите )а нельзя все нужные файлы держать в одной директории и потом общим путем вызывать разные файлы с этой директории?

Comment: Задача внутри темплейта заинклюдить файл с html кодом. А имя файла или целиком путь, брать из ACF

Comment: Не, выводит просто url, а не содержимое файла

Comment: попробуйте просто include() или require() вообще не должно ничего отображаться если пусто будет и проверьте переменную print_r($test); на содержимое

Comment: print_r показывает путь к файлу, но не его содержимое. Просто include пробовал, то же самое. Require выводит также путь, а дальше обрывает загрузку страницы.

Comment: Вот я же говорил - ты придумал РЕШЕНИЕ (имя файла в произвольные поле) и спрашиваешь как его решить. Лучше бы спрашивал как правильно решить ЗАДАЧУ. Вот для чего нужно имя ФАЙЛА там прописывать. что в тоге должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Для включения части шаблона в ВП существует функция [get_template_part](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2/get_template_part).
Так же некоторые др функции позволяют работать с "запчастями" шаблонов 
(get_header, get_footer и др)

Однако писать имя ФАЙЛА в произвольное поле - логически не верно. Пользователь в админке не должен оперировать такими "низкоуровневыми" понятиями.

Comment: сейчас реализовано так <?php $block = include ('inc/dir/'.(get_field('filename'))); echo $block; ?> 
а filename в ACF селектор, filename.php : Смысл файла

Comment: @I'mRegistered сие есть неправильно. Не должен юзер работать  с файлами (кроме как из медиатеки). Тем более с php.